# Filter list of dicts based on some condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have following list

```
[
<class 'supapi.classes.Offer'>: {'currency': 'RUR', 'date_from': '2020-02-18', 'rub_value': '62.00'}, 
<class 'supapi.classes.Offer'>: {'currency': 'RUR', 'date_from': '2020-02-16', 'rub_value': '50.00'}, 
<class 'supapi.classes.Offer'>: {'currency': 'RUR', 'date_from': '2020-02-30', 'rub_value': '0.00'}, 
<class 'supapi.classes.Offer'>: {'currency': 'RUR', 'date_from': '2019-11-25', 'rub_value': '5.00'}
]
```

I would like to filter that list based on last date condition and not future date.
For example, after filtration i want get only `[<class 'supapi.classes.Offer'>: {'currency': 'RUR', 'date_from': '2020-02-18', 'rub_value': '62.00'}]` because it's last current date and not future date

I figure out that i can compare date using datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y-%m-%d')

Comment: why `'2020-02-18'` in your case last(and not valid) date is `'2020-02-30`' ?

Comment: Besause todays date 18.02 , 20.02 if future date

Comment: Try sorting the list using, eg epoch as the key, filter to remove any future days, then take the last (or first depending on the sort - ascending / descending) item.

Comment: 02-30 is not a valid date because February never has 30 days. There is a problem with your data.

Comment: BTW your example data has a incorrect date '2020-02-30'. February has only 28 days or 29 if it's leap year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get the objects with `date_from` set to the current date, you can create a string with the same format and compare them.

```
this_day = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
result = filter(lambda e: e.date_from == this_day, offers_list)
```

**Updated answer**

If you want the object with the newest `date_from` you could first filter the future values out with `filter` and the use `max` to find the correct one.

```
from datetime import datetime, date
result = filter(lambda e: datetime.strptime(e.date_from, '%Y-%m-%d').date() <= date.today() , offers_list)
value = max(result, key=lambda e: datetime.strptime(e.date_from, '%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Comment: Yea, i worked, thank you, but what if today is 19.02, and i still want to get 18.02 but not 20.02? This is kinda my sutuation: i want get last date regarding of today but not future date.

Comment: See my updated answer for how to get the newest value which is not in the future.

Comment: @AlexNikitin Did you find the updated answer useful?

Answer (score 0):

I also figure out own solution

```
return list(
            filter(
                lambda e: datetime.strptime(e.date_from, '%Y-%m-%d') == max(
                    [datetime.strptime(item.date_from, '%Y-%m-%d') for item in list_to_sort
                     if datetime.strptime(item.date_from, '%Y-%m-%d') <= datetime.today()]
                ), offers)
        )
```